# Visual Studio 11 Crashes

Tags: visual-studio

I have a funky problem... I installed IIS7 to my development server where I had Visual Studio 11 as well. Then I installed PHP 5.5 and now somehow Visual Studio crashes when I try to load solutions.

What causes that, and how can I fix it?

Some errors:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time
> stamp: 0x5011ecaa Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
> 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x0000c41f Faulting process id: 0x7b8 Faulting
> application start time: 0x01cecfcb703b640a Faulting application path:
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Faulting module path: C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
> b2efd82d-3bbe-11e3-93af-b433428ecf9e
>
> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
> process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException
> Stack:    at
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportDefinition,
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AtomicComposition)    at
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(System.Type,
> System.Type, System.String,
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportCardinality)    at
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[[System.__Canon,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.String,
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ImportCardinality)    at
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[System.__Canon,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]    at
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValue[System.__Canon,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetService[System.__Canon,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.CommonIconHelper.Initialize(System.IServiceProvider)
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.LanguageService.CSharp.IconHelper.Initialize(System.IServiceProvider)
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.LanguageService.CSharp.CSLanSvcProvider.InitializeProvider()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.LanguageService.CSharp.CSLanSvcProvider.EnsureInitialized()
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32)    at
> MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
> at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
> IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
> Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
> System.Object, Int32)    at
> MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
> System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
> System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Comment: Did VS work after you installed IIS7?

Comment: Yes, it did worked well. But now I'm thinking I downloaded and installed latest updates for Windows Server 2008 R2, maybe they broke it?

Comment: Sounds like it was working but you've done multiple installations / system changes since... It's going to be hard to find out what did it. You may be better off rolling the system back (system restore)

Comment: I updated Visual Studio with the latest update and it opened a solution for me, but with this error: http://screencast.com/t/ZPwXb8iKl0H

Comment: And here's the error log: http://pastebin.com/B9W3v4F3 it appears that there is something wrong with MySQL connector maybe ?

Comment: Can you try in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/Llhzhra5HFPw this is what I get when I try to run my program in safe mode

Comment: I think I fixed it. http://screencast.com/t/leO7DXOMZ I had 2x MySQl Tools for Visual Studio. So I disabled one and I don't get errors anymore right now..

Comment: Well done you, I'm sorry I couldn't have been more help.